# PIL Image opened via StringIO returns NoneType error when saving

Tags: python, io, python-imaging-library

I am receiving a stream of images using a client/server similar to what is found here: http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.3/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream

This is the server portion:

```
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
    server_socket.listen(0)

    connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
    try:
            while True:
                    image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(4))[0]
                    if not image_len:
                            break
            #       image_stream = io.BytesIO()
                    image_stream = StringIO()
                    image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))

                    image_stream.seek(0)
                    image = Image.open(image_stream)
                    print('image is %dx%d' % image.size)
                    print(type(image))
                    image.verify()
                    img_io = StringIO()
            #       img_io = io.BytesIO()
                    image.save('/tmp/test.jpg')
                    image.save(img_io, format='PNG', quality=70)
                    img_io.seek(0)
            #       print('image is verified')
                    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/png')
    finally:
            connection.close()
            server_socket.close()
```

The connection is made successfully, although the following is returned:

```
image is 640x480
<type 'instance'>
File "/camserver.py", line 29, in start_server image.save('/tmp/test.jpg')
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1406, in save
self.load()
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 170, in load
read = self.fp.read
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I've tried multiple combinations of BytesIO and StringIO, and it looks like the size attribute of the image is returned as expected, but I am unable to save it to either a file-like object or an actual file.

EDIT: Omid has it. From the docs on .verify:

"...Also, if you need to load the image after using this method, you must reopen the image file"

Comment: Remove `image.verify()` line. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3385643/538284

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python PIL load throwing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385561/python-pil-load-throwing-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-rea)