# How to resize image in django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, python-imaging-library

I have the following `ModelForm`:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.fields['image'].validators = []

    def clean_image(self):
        img = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        if not img:
            return img
        # Resize to Max 1024x1024 px
        new_size = (1024, 1024)
        if any(x>new_size[0] for x in img.image.size):
            img.image.thumbnail(new_size)
        return img
```

It throws an error, when I try upload an image:

> Exception Type: AttributeError at /some/view
>   Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Full traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py" in load
  147.             read = self.load_read

During handling of the above exception ('JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_read'), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/django/portal/views/advert.py" in post
  167.         if not all([f.is_valid() for f in (usr_form, adv_form)]):

File "/opt/django/portal/views/advert.py" in <listcomp>
  167.         if not all([f.is_valid() for f in (usr_form, adv_form)]):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  384.         self._clean_fields()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  405.                     value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()

File "/opt/django/portal/forms.py" in clean_image
  57.             img.image.thumbnail(new_size)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in thumbnail
  2008.         im = self.resize(size, resample)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in resize
  1697.         self.load()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py" in load
  151.             read = self.fp.read

Exception Type: AttributeError at /some/view
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I suppose it's because of how the `ImageField` is [implemented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/fields/#ImageField) in `django`:

```
image = Image.open(file)
# verify() must be called immediately after the constructor.
image.verify()

# Annotating so subclasses can reuse it for their own validation
f.image = image
```

According to some [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385643/2146346) I should reopen the image file after the `verify()` has been called, but I'm not sure how can I do this or whether that's the best approach of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `ImageField` by default verifies that the uploaded file contains a valid image, in fact it hands over image data to `PIL` to process. One could subclass `ImageField` and override its `to_python` method so that the resize filters are applied on the first step of validation, however it's more convenient to implement custom `clean_*` method, here's an example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)


class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    def clean_image(self):
        img = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        if not img:
            return img
        maxdim = 1024
        if any(dim > maxdim for dim in img.image.size):
            # Resize too large image up to the max_size
            from PIL import Image
            i = Image.open(img.file)
            fmt = i.format.lower()
            i.thumbnail((maxdim, maxdim))
            # We must reset io.BytesIO object, otherwise resized image bytes
            # will get appended to the original image  
            img.file = type(img.file)()
            i.save(img.file, fmt)
        return img

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

Things to note:

- Original image `bytes` are stored in the `img.file` attribute
- `img.file` is an instance of the `io.BytesIO`
- `PIL.Image` instance of the orig. image is stored in the `img.image` attribute

Comment: This works, thank you! But not for Temporary Files. Every file above 2.5MB (default setting) resolves to an error as it is not saved in memory.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers

Comment: I'm getting: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'file' and 'name'