# Pillow gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek' when trying to save a file

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a view in Django, using Django REST Framework and its `FileUploadParser`, where I can upload an image to, and it then stores both the original image and a thumbnail.

```py
class ImageUploadParser(FileUploadParser):
    media_type = "image/*"


class ImageUploadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = [ImageUploadParser]

    def post(self, request, filename):
        if "file" not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty content")

        file_obj = request.data["file"]

        try:
            img = Image.open(file_obj)
            img.verify()
        except UnidentifiedImageError:
            raise ParseError("Unsupported image type")

        path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT / f"{request.user.id}"
        unique = uuid.uuid4().hex
        extension = img.format.lower()
        filename_full = f"{unique}.{extension}"
        filename_thumb = f"{unique}.thumb.{extension}"

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)

        img.thumbnail((580, 580), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save(path / filename_thumb, "image/png", optimize=True)

        return Response(f"{request.user.id}/{filename_full}", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When I post a file, this is the error I get:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/uploads/upload/test.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 182, in load
    seek = self.load_seek
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 529, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: load_seek

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 448, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/current_thread_executor.py", line 22, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 490, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 55, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/criticalnotes/uploads/views.py", line 74, in post
    img.thumbnail((580, 580), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2618, in thumbnail
    im = self.resize(size, resample, box=box, reducing_gap=reducing_gap)
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2156, in resize
    self.load()
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/cn-django/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 185, in load
    seek = self.fp.seek
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, what is `None`, because `img` is not `None` at least.

Comment: I would double check what `file_obj` is. If it's `None`, I can see that causing that error.

Comment: It is not None, it is a file object with a seek method. I can write it to disk using standard `open` and `write` calls just fine, but I can't write it via Pillow.

Comment: Please ensure your example is the very least amount of code that reproduces the problem... else you are looking for someone to help you from a very small pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Pillow's `verify()` function closes the underlying file descriptor, after which functions like `seek` no longer exist internally.

You will need to use `PIL.Image.open()` to open the `Image` again before calling `save()`.

For reference, see:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30252
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ImageField
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385643